# WIF, Duplex and Bindings

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wif

I've used WIF to create a STS but how can I get Duplex callbacks working.

The current binding i'm using is WS2007FederationHttp. Which I'm lead to believe doesn't support Duplex.

Can WIF support duplex?

Answer (score 0):

WIF can but that federation binding doesn't out of the box.  You'll want to do something like:

```
        // Setting RequireClientCertificate = true enables mutual authentication (2 way SSL), originally disabled for WS2007FederationHttpBinding
        HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBinding = outputBinding.Elements.Find<HttpsTransportBindingElement>();
        httpsBinding.RequireClientCertificate = true;
```

Comment: the question was asking for duplex communication, where your answer is for 2 way trust in building the ssl connection.