# any equivalent binding like wsDualHttpBinding, which works for WIF for federated security?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wif

I'm looking to setup a wsDualHttpBinding wcf endpoint to provide WCF eventing.  However, the rest of my application uses WIF to provide authN/authZ support via Claims security. For those endpoints protected by WIF, I'm using WS2007FederationHttpBinding

Is there any pre-existing binding like WS2007FederationHttpBinding, except with duplex support?

Comment: Possible duplicate.  This is the only answer I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501625/wif-duplex-and-bindings.

Comment: yep, pretty much the same question. no correct answers there either.

Comment: Short answer: I don't think there is an option that supports duplex.

Comment: yup, looks like custom binding maybe the only option. another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499228/dualchannel-binding-over-federation-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no duplex binding for federated wcf.

Thus I'm now on plan B.  use existing WS2007FederationHttpBinding, and create a long polling WCF operation to simulate duplex behavior. One side benefit of this approach is that its firewall friendly.